# Post Request from vue to SpringBoot will be blocked

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js

I am starting to test a little bit with vue.js and spring boot and build a simple login/registration site.

The registration and the login are working fine. I can send a JSON with registration data from vue to spring boot and it will insert the data in a database. After that I can send username and password and I will receive a Bearer Token from spring boot.

So my target is to call a RestEndpoint only if I am logged in/authenticated.
I created a simple RestEndpoint:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @PostMapping(path = "/api/v1/testendpoint")
    public String getData() {
        return "Data are comming through";
    }
}
```

And I got the following WebSecurityConfig:

```
httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/registration/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/login/**")
                .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl();
```

This should send a post request to the testendpoint:

```
let token = 'abc';

    axios.post("http://localhost:8886/api/v1/testendpoint", {
        headers: {"Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`}
    });
```

But my request is getting blocked:
[image]

So as I wanted the WebSecurityConfig like this:

- registration and login Endpoints are accessable for everyone
- every other request like "/api/v1/testendpoint" are only available if you are logged in

I thought that I did this with the configuration `.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/v1/registration/**").permitAll()`
`.antMatchers("/api/v1/login/**").permitAll()`
`.anyRequest().authenticated();`

Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Cheers,
Michael

**UPDATE**

I forgot to look into the console. There is the following error:

[image]

It means that cross-origin is forbidden by external sources.
But I enabled it with the Annotation @CrossOrigin in my Controller.

I don't understand this.

**Update**
Found my mistake:
I need to add .cors to the WebSecurityConfig. That was all...

Answer (score 0):

you can disable  `cors` in configuration like csrf disabled. `.and().cors().disable()`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work.